# Unity 2d detect collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am building my first 2D project in unity, I am stuck in the PlayerMovement script, it's not colliding with neither the walls nor the objects the player is supposed to move by one block and it should push the objects (like in sokoban), but it's not detecting any of these
the player is a capsule which has a capsule collider 2d component and a rigidbody 2d component and the each wall bloack has box collider 2d and tilemap and tilemap collider 2d and a rigidbody 2d.
I tried using the OnDrawGismos() method to detect the object before moving but it's not working
here's my code

````
    public Tilemap wall;
    private Vector3 moveToPosition;
    private Vector3 movement;
    private bool walking;
    private float moveSpeed = 2;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!walking)
        {


            movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            movement.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

           

            if (movement != Vector3.zero)
            {
                moveToPosition = transform.position + new Vector3(movement.x, movement.y, 0);
                Vector3Int wallMapTile = wall.WorldToCell(moveToPosition - new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0));

                if (wall.GetTile(wallMapTile) == null)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(Move(moveToPosition));
                }
            }
        }


       
        
    }


    IEnumerator Move(Vector3 newPos)
    {
        walking = true;
        while ((newPos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.position = newPos;

        walking = false;
    }
    

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(moveToPosition- new Vector3(0,0.5f,0), 0.2f);
    }```
````

Comment: What are the rigidbody components `Body Type` and are any constraints set?

Comment: If you move by changing the position it teleports and bypasses physics

Answer (score 0):

use rb.velocity to control the player movement instead of transform.position because the player would be teleporting not walking